# Persist functor in a realtional database

Tags: java, database, playframework-2.2, functor, ebean

I have a Java Entity that has several well defined functors. I want to persist them so as not factorize the object once it is fetched from the database. Is there a way to do so with Ebean?

I think that I could get it saving the class name that implements those functors as a String in the entity and in the setter of that string implement the setter of the functor with Reflection. Any other idea?

Class Example:

```
@Entity
public Foo extends Model
{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Transient
   private Runnable functor;

   private String classFunctor;

   public void setClassFunctor(String value)
   {
       //Here I implement the Reflection routine to load the functor.
   }
}
```

Comment: I've saved Java bytecode into a BLOB field. I had to write the functor as a public class and compile to bytecode before saving to database, so a ClassLoader could load it. Then used *Class.newInstance()* to reconstitute the functor instance after loading the class.

Comment: I do not knot so much about Java bytecode... but is there any dependence in the code inserted in the functor object or I can write whatever I like with all the dependencies I need and the single class bytecode is enough?

Comment: Unfortunately, for this approach to work, all dependencies would have to be coded into the functor class so it could reconstitute its own state upon construction of an instance.

Comment: Ok, so I think I will follow the steps described in the question.